# Uber sdk integration error

Tags: android, uber-api

I'm getting some message on clicking Uber ride request widget. I used the same code from this [link](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk) in a different app and its working. Am I doing something wrong here? I tried with different client_id and server_token but got the same result. I thought may be the pick and drop locations might be too far so I edited the locations to be near still got the same response.

```html
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "<MY_CLIENT_ID>";
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "https://www.google.com";
private static final String SERVER_TOKEN = "<MY_SERVER_TOKEN>";

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

  PICKUP_LAT = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
  PICKUP_LONG = gpsTracker.getLongitude();


  System.out.println("picklatlng"+ " "+PICKUP_LAT + " " +PICKUP_LONG);

  LocationAddress locationAddress = new LocationAddress();
  locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());

  fetchdrop();



}

private void fetchdrop(){
  String url = getResources().getString(R.string.app_base_url)+ "&action=eventdetails&id=" + product_id;
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {


      try {
       JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
       JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("EventsList");
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject main = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        drop_nick = main.getString("app_venue").trim();
        drop_addr = main.getString("app_location");
        drop_lat= Double.parseDouble(main.getString("app_lat"));
        drop_lng = Double.parseDouble(main.getString("app_lang"));
        System.out.println("UberSAM_dropdetails" + " "+ drop_nick +" "+drop_addr+" "+drop_lat+" "+drop_lng);
        uberConfig();
       }




      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // JSON error
       e.printStackTrace();
       Toast.makeText(Event_Details_Activity.this, "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

     }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(Event_Details_Activity.this, "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
  }) {
            /*@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                return params;
            }*/

  };

  RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Event_Details_Activity.this);
  requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}

private void uberConfig() {

  SessionConfiguration configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
    .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setServerToken(SERVER_TOKEN)
    .build();



  validateConfiguration(configuration);
  ServerTokenSession session = new ServerTokenSession(configuration);

  Log.e("EventDetailActivity", "session:" + session.getAuthenticator());


  System.out.println("UberSAM"+" "+"DROPOFF_ADDR:"+" "+drop_addr);
  System.out.println("UberSAM"+" "+"DROPOFF_NICK:"+" "+drop_nick);
  System.out.println("UberSAM"+" "+"DROPOFF_LAT:"+" "+drop_lat);
  System.out.println("UberSAM"+" "+"DROPOFF_LONG:"+" "+drop_lng);

  System.out.println("UberSAM"+" "+"PICKUP_ADDR:"+" "+PICKUP_ADDR);
  System.out.println("UberSAM"+" "+"PICKUP_NICK:"+" "+PICKUP_NICK);
  System.out.println("UberSAM"+" "+"PICKUP_LAT:"+" "+PICKUP_LAT);
  System.out.println("UberSAM"+" "+"PICKUP_LONG:"+" "+PICKUP_LONG);

  RideParameters rideParametersForProduct = new RideParameters.Builder()
    //.setProductId(UBERX_PRODUCT_ID)
    .setPickupLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, PICKUP_NICK, PICKUP_ADDR)
    .setDropoffLocation(drop_lat, drop_lng, drop_nick, drop_addr)
    .build();

  RideRequestButton blackButton = (RideRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_white_1);

  RideRequestActivityBehavior rideRequestActivityBehavior = new RideRequestActivityBehavior(this,
    WIDGET_REQUEST_CODE, configuration);



  blackButton.setRequestBehavior(rideRequestActivityBehavior);
  blackButton.setRideParameters(rideParametersForProduct);
  blackButton.setSession(session);
  blackButton.loadRideInformation();
  blackButton.setCallback(this);


}

private void validateConfiguration(SessionConfiguration configuration) {
  String nullError = "%s must not be null";
  String sampleError = "Please update your %s in the gradle.properties of the project before " +
    "using the Uber SDK Sample app. For a more secure storage location, " +
    "please investigate storing in your user home gradle.properties ";

  checkNotNull(configuration, String.format(nullError, "SessionConfiguration"));
  checkNotNull(configuration.getClientId(), String.format(nullError, "Client ID"));
  checkNotNull(configuration.getRedirectUri(), String.format(nullError, "Redirect URI"));
  checkNotNull(configuration.getServerToken(), String.format(nullError, "Server Token"));
  checkState(!configuration.getClientId().equals("insert_your_client_id_here"),
    String.format(sampleError, "Client ID"));
  checkState(!configuration.getRedirectUri().equals("insert_your_redirect_uri_here"),
    String.format(sampleError, "Redirect URI"));
  checkState(!configuration.getRedirectUri().equals("insert_your_server_token_here"),
    String.format(sampleError, "Server Token"));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the Uber account you used to authenticate with your app (implementing the widget) already started a ride from within a different app. [The widget leverages the `ride_widgets` scope](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/ride-request-widget#implicit-grant-authorization), but it does not include access to trips requested from within a different app. You can end the currently existing trip and try again. The widget should work as expected.

Just FYI, [you can check out the `all_trips`](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/scopes#steps-to-request-full-access) scope to see what additional approval you would need to see trips of Uber account that were requested through e.g. the Uber app or other API integrations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I simply uninstalled my app and then reinstalled it. Its now working fine.